# How to save the config file data in a variable and pass it to another template to iterate the values and perform the task in azure pipelines

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to iterate a list of objects to perform a task in azure pipelines. So what I've done is I am uploading a config.json file to azure pipeline's secure files library with the format of below,

```
{
  data: [
    {
      name: "Name 1",
      version: 2
    },
    {
      name: "Name 2",
      version: 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Then i am downloading the file using the DownloadSecureFile@1 and i am extracting the data using PythonScript@0 task, the code I used for this is below,

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
     scriptSource: inline
     script: |
       import argparse, json, sys
       parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
       parser.add_argument("--filePath", help="Provide the json file path")
       args = parser.parse_args()
       with open(args.filePath, 'r') as f:
       data = json.load(f)
       data = json.dumps(data)
       print(data)
       print('##vso[task.setvariable variable=helmConfigs;]%s' % (data))
       
       print("##vso[task.setvariable variable=someVar]" + data)
     arguments: --filePath $(Agent.TempDirectory)/config.json
     failOnStderr: true
```

Then I added a powershell script in the same file to print the above and it works fine. But when I am trying to pass it another template file, I am receiving an error like this:

> The term 'someVar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable  program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again.

This is how I have called the template file,

```
- template: templates/config-template.yml
   parameters:
      someVar: $(someVar)
```

This is the config-template.yml;

```
parameters:
  - name: someVar
    type: object
    default: {}

steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host "python var = $(someVar)"
```

So what I need is that after extracting the above information from the config.json file, I need to iterate the array and perform some operations inside the config-template.yml file. For instance, let's say I need to iterate that array and print the name and the version of each object in bash or powershell. How to achieve that? Any guidance on this would be highly appreciated.